# Hide Bootstrap4 nav link when viewing page on iphone

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I find myself in a bind yet again and in need of help.
How can I hide one of my boostrap4 nav links (Link2) when the page is viewed on an iphone?
Any help is much appreciated. 
Thank you in advance.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navigation">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-1">Link1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-2">Link2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-4">Link3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the responsive [display utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/)...

```
<li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline">
   <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-2">Link2</a>
</li>
```

- `d-none` = hide on xs
- `d-sm-inline` = show on small and up

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/NRziW1b3wh)